# Crontab not working

Tags: magento-1.7, cron

I have created a simple module with a config file and one observer to run a cron every minute. But the cron is not registering in the database as well as not executing at all. I tried running cron.php manually still no results. Here is my module's files:

*config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Inic_Icron>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Inic_Icron>
</modules>
<global>        
    <models>
        <cron>
            <class>Inic_Icron_Model</class>
        </cron>
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <inic_icron_import_data>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>icron/observer::importdata</model>
            </run>
        </inic_icron_import_data>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

*Observer.php*

```
class Inic_Icron_Model_Observer
{
    public function importdata() {
        Mage::log("WORKS!");
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have cleared cache and tried running it manually still not result. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Make sure that your system.log file as full permission otherwise you can print something inside importdata function.check error log as well

Comment: Yes the log file as full permissions and there are no error logs getting generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because you defined the model alias as `cron`

```
<cron><!-- model alias here-->
    <class>Inic_Icron_Model</class>
</cron>
```

and in your cron you call the model with alias `icron`:

```
<model>icron/observer::importdata</model>
```

Also make sure the module is loaded. I mean check if the file `app/etc/modules/Inic_Icron.xml` exists. You might want to clear the cache also.

Comment: That was the issue. Now the cron is getting registered in the table.